# number of hash buckets

Tags: java, hashmap

In the [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) documentation, it is mentioned that:

- the **initial capacity** is simply the capacity at the time the hash table is created
- the **capacity** is the number of buckets in the hash table.

Now suppose we have intial capacity of 16 (default), and if we keep adding elements to 100 nos, the capacity of hashmap is 100 * loadfactor.

Will the number of hash buckets is 100 or 16?

**Edit:**
From the solution I read: buckets are more than the elements added.
Taking this as view point: so if we add Strings as key, we will get one element/bucket resulting in a lot of space consumption/complexity, is my understanding right ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Neither 100 nor 16 buckets.  Most likely there will be 256 buckets, but this isn't guaranteed by the documentation.

From the [updated documentation link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html):

> The load factor is a measure of how full the hash table is allowed to get before its capacity is automatically increased. When the number of entries in the hash table exceeds the product of the load factor and the current capacity, the hash table is rehashed (that is, internal data structures are rebuilt) so that the hash table has *approximately twice* the number of buckets.

(emphasis mine)

So, if we ignore the word "approximately" above, we determine that whenever the hash table becomes 75% full (or whichever load factor you specify in the constructor), the number of hash buckets doubles.  That means that the number of buckets doubles whenever you insert the 12th, 24th, 48th, and 96th elements, leaving a total of 256 buckets.

However, as I emphasized in the documentation snippet, the number is *approximately* twice the previous size, so it may not be exactly 256.  In fact, if the second-to-last doubling is replaced with a slightly larger increase, the last doubling may never happen, so the final hash table may be as small as 134 buckets, or may be larger than 256 elements.

N.B. I arrived at the 134 number because it's the smallest integer `N` such that `0.75 * N > 100`.

Comment: +1 for citing the doc. Just a side note: from the Java 7 source it looks like the capacity is _exactly_ doubled (or quadrupled or more, when `putAll()` is used with a large map) - in fact there's this comment on the buckets table: `Length MUST Always be a power of two.`  - AFAIK there's no approximation for a power of two :)

Comment: @Adam is my guess correct: as per the discussion above,hashbuckets will remain more than the number of keys in hashmap, thus chance for a collision should be zero, if diff Integers are taken as key ?

Comment: @Naroji Just because there are more buckets than keys in a hash table does *not* make collisions impossible, even if all the keys are unique.  In some problems it is possible to design such a hash function (this is called a perfect hash) if you really tailor your hash function to your domain, and your hash function is allowed to consider the hash table size, but this is not the case in Java.  In a hash table of size N, most implementations will produce a collision if given two keys whose hash codes differ by kN for some integer k.

Comment: @Adam taking example : hashtable size:16(hashcode from 1 to 16), and as i add the 12/13th element, the bucket size increases to 32(diff hashcodes). now when I add 24/26th element, it should go to bucket 24/26th(and not to 12/13th bucket). does this does not make sense

Comment: @Naroji I'm not sure I understand your question.  My point is that the Java `hashCode()` method doesn't depend on the size of the hash table, and not only can two different objects have the same hash code, but two different object with different hash codes can be placed into the same bucket because the number of buckets in the hash table is far smaller than the number of possible return values from `hashCode()`.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the source code of `HashMap` we see the following:

```
threshold = capacity * loadfactor
size = number of elements in the map

if( size >= threshold ) {
  double capacity
}
```

Thus, if the initial capacity is 16 and your load factor is 0.75 (the default), the initial threshold will be 12. If you add the 12th element, the capacity rises to 32 with a threshold of 24. The next step would be capacity 64 and threshold 48 etc. etc.

So with 100 elements, you should have a capacity of 256 and a threshold of 192.

Note that this applies only to the standard values. If you know the approximate number of elements your map will contain you should create it with a high enough initial capacity in order to prevent the copying around when the capacity is increased.

*Update*:

A word on the capacity: it will always be a power of two, even if you define a different initial capacity. The hashmap will then set the capacity to the smallest power of 2 that is greater than or equal to the provided initial capacity.

Comment: @Thomas thanks for the nice answer...one doubt....does capacity means "no of hash buckets" ?

Comment: @jain007 I'll cite the doc as well: `...the "capacity" of the HashMap instance (the number of buckets)...` - so, yes, the capacity is the number of buckets.

Comment: @Thomas Then what do you mean by 12 elements are present? Does it mean Hashmap has 12 key or 12 buckets have at least one element mapped?

Comment: @piechuckerr I'm not sure what confuses you but with elements I mean entries in the map, i.e. values mapped to keys (and thus you could say elements = keys in some sense).

Answer (score 1):

From your link :

> When the number of entries in the hash table exceeds the product of the load factor and the current capacity, the capacity is roughly doubled by calling the rehash method.

That means if we have initial capacity 16 and when it exceeds, capacity will be increased by 32, next time by 64 and so on.

In your case, you are adding 100 nos. So when you come to 16th number, size will be added by 32 so now total size 48. Again you keep adding till 48th number now size will be increased by 64. Thus, in your case, total size of bucket is 112.

Answer (score 1):

In [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

```
When the number of entries in the hash table exceeds the product of the 
load factor and the current capacity, the capacity is roughly doubled by 
calling the rehash method.

threshold=product of the  load factor and the current capacity
```

Lets try.. initial size of hashmap  is 16
and default load factor is `0.75`  so 1st threshold is 12 so adding 12  element next capacity will be.. 
(16*2) =32
2st threshold is 24 so  after adding  24th element next capacity will be (32*2)=64

and so on..

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have *at least* one bucket per actual item.  If you add items beyond 16, the table must be resized and rehashed.

> Now suppose we have intial capacity of 16 (default), and if we keep
>   adding elements to 100 nos, the capacity of hashmap is 100 *
>   loadfactor.

Actually it says:

> If the initial capacity is greater than the maximum number of entries
>   divided by the load factor, no rehash operations will ever occur.

Ie, if there is a maximum of 100 items and the capacity is 100/0.75 = 133, then no re-hashing should ever occur.  Notice that this implies that *even if the table is not full*, it may have to be rehashed when close to full.  So the ideal initial capacity to set using the default load factor, if you expect <=100 items, is ~135+.