# Java - Calculating the load factor

Tags: java

I am trying to calculate the load factor of my Hashtable and print out the result. However, when I run this, the load factor is equal to 2. This is currently the size of my map - so my method loadFactor is not quite working. Is there something obvious I am missing? ( i am fairly new to Java)

```
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
public class Main  {
    Student student;
    Hashtable next;
    public Hashtable<String,Student> studentMap;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Hashtable<String, String> studentMap = new Hashtable<>(10000, 0.75f);
        studentMap.keySet().forEach((key) -> {
            String value = studentMap.get(key);
            System.out.println("Key = " + key + ", Value = " + value);
        });   
        //adding values to array
        studentMap.put("16012804", "Jennifer");
        studentMap.put("13747732", "Beatrice");
        studentMap.put("14058392", "Bob");
        Set set = studentMap.entrySet();
        Iterator iterator = set.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry mapentry = (Map.Entry)iterator.next();
            System.out.print("key is: "+ mapentry.getKey() + " & Value is: ");
            System.out.println(mapentry.getValue());
        }
        //Get values based on key
        String var= studentMap.get("16012804");
        System.out.println("Value at index 1 is: "+var);
        // Remove values based on key
        studentMap.remove("16012804");
        System.out.println("Map key and values after removal:");
        Set set2 = studentMap.entrySet();
        Iterator iterator2 = set2.iterator();
        while(iterator2.hasNext()) {
          Map.Entry mapentry2 = (Map.Entry)iterator2.next();
          System.out.print("Key is: "+mapentry2.getKey() + " & Value is: ");
          System.out.println(mapentry2.getValue());
        }
        Set keyset = studentMap.keySet();
        System.out.println("Key set values are:" + keyset);
        boolean val = studentMap.isEmpty();
        System.out.println("Is hash map empty: " + val);
        System.out.println("Size of the Hashtable " + studentMap.size());
        System.out.println("Load Factor: " + loadFactor(studentMap));
        System.out.println("Hash: " + studentMap.hashCode());
        System.out.println("Size of map is now: " +  mapcapacity(studentMap));


    }
    public static float loadFactor(Map studentMap){
    int count=0;
    float load;
    for(int i=0; i<studentMap.size(); i++){
            count += studentMap.size();
    }
    load = count/(float)studentMap.size();
    return load;
    }
    //if the size of the map is greater than the map capacity * load factor - then double the size of map. 
    public static Integer mapcapacity(Map studentMap){
       Integer initCapacity=2;
       float loadFactor=0.75f;
       boolean capacityFound=false;
        Integer capacity=initCapacity;
        Integer size=studentMap.size();
        while(!capacityFound){
            if(size>capacity*loadFactor){
                capacity=capacity*2;

            }
            else {
                capacityFound=true;

            }
        }
        return capacity;

    }
    public int hash(String key){
       return (Math.abs(key.hashCode())) % studentMap.size();  
    }



}
```

Comment: You know that `for(int i=0; i<studentMap.size(); i++){
            count += studentMap.size();
    }` is the same as `count = studentMap.size() * studentMap.size()` right ? what are you trying to do ? this is definitely **not** calculating the load factor...

Comment: oh dear maybe i'm a long way off  ... I am trying to calculate the load factor of the size of the studentMap, which is my hash table

Comment: and how can you calculate anything like that ???

Comment: You literally can't get the load factor of a `java.util.Hashtable`.  It doesn't expose any API for getting the size of the hash table, just the number of distinct entries that have been put in the table.

Comment: This is what the load factor is (sounds like you need a better understanding) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379433/number-of-hash-buckets. The number of buckets starts out with a default of 16. It increases its capacity from there by double, so 32, 64, etc. It activates when 75% of the table is filled. Use this information to calculate how many buckets you have. Hope this helps.

Comment: i think my problem is i am trying to work out how many things are in my hash table and divide it by the size of the hash table - but for both things i am using studentMap.size().

Comment: Louis is right, it sounds like you're trying to compute `size/capacity` only that there is no way for you to know what is the `capacity`. Further, all we know is that `size/capacity <= loadFactor` - and in most cases it'll be `<` - so even that doesn't give you the load factor.

Comment: Why would you need this? This feels a lot like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) to me. Anyway, you can do this quite easily with some reflection.

Comment: thanks @ToddSewell , i am looking at reflection now

Comment: You still didn't explain why you need this.